# Directory not found in file explorer after being created using flutter code

Tags: android, flutter

I created a directory using Flutter, to confirm the directory was created successfully I run the app for the second time and it shows the directory already exists,
but I can't see the directory in the file browser.

I also tried to create a text file in the directory, and
tried to rename some photos to the directory

The code I used to create the directory :

```
    Future createDir(String path) async
  {

    final dirName = new io.Directory(await getAppPath + "/Photo/Products");
    dirName.exists().then((isThere){
      isThere ? print("The Directory Exists Path is : " + dirName.path)
          : dirName.create(recursive: true).then((io.Directory directory){
        print("Create Directory Path is : " + directory.path);
      });
    });
  }

    Future<String> get getAppPath async
  {
    String resutl;
    io.Directory appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    resutl = appDirectory.path;
    return resutl;
  }
```

Creating text file :

```
File saveTest = File(photoSavePaht + '/' + 'test.txt');
print('Save Test path : ' + saveTest.path);
saveTest.writeAsString('Test Text to save');
```

Renaming photo :

```
File movPhoto = File(savedPhoto);
movPhoto.rename(_productImage.path);
```

I did not get any error message after running these code segments.

Comment: It created in application directory, not on the Internal Storage that you can access easily

Comment: thank you for the comment I am new in Flutter could you explain more how can I fix this issue